# Special chars in Amazon S3 keys?

Tags: amazon-s3

Is it possible to have special characters like åäö in the key? If i urlencode the key before storing it works, but i cant really find a way to access the object. If i write åäö in the url i get access denied (like i get if the object is not found). If i urlencode the url i paste in the browser i get "InvalidURICouldn't parse the specified URI".

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Found out that it works if i urlencode two times so that i encode % to %25 for the accessurl. Would be nice if it was possible to store it with the special char without urlencoding though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon supports key names with Unicode characters.  You do not need to URL encode the key name when you upload a file to Amazon.  You do need to URL encode the key name when you generate a download URL.

If you upload a file named åäö.txt to a bucket named mybucket, the download URL will be http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/%C3%A5%C3%A4%C3%B6.txt