# File name "@" character is replaced with "%40" in uploading file to AWS S3 in Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am developing an Android application. In my application, I am uploading file to AWS S3 bucket. I can upload the file successfully now to the s3 bucket using AWS Android SDK. But the problem is the "@" character in the filename is replaced with "%40" on the s3 Bucket.

This is my code for uploading file to S3

```
   public void s3credentialsProvider()
   {
      CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
         this.context,
         AwsUtility.COGNITO_POOL_ID,
         AwsUtility.BUCKET_REGION
      );
      createAmazonS3Client(cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider   );
   }


   public void createAmazonS3Client(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider
                                       credentialsProvider){

      if(s3Client==null)
      {
         // Create an S3 client
         s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

         // Set the region of your S3 bucket
         s3Client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(AwsUtility.BUCKET_REGION));
      }
   }

   public void setTransferUtility(){

      transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client, context);
   }

   public CachedFile uploadFileTos3(CachedFile cachedFile)
   {

      File file = new File(Utilities.getRealPathFromUri(context, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(cachedFile.getFilePath()))));
      String fileHash = Utilities.getFileMD5Hash(file);
      cachedFile.setFileHash(fileHash);

      String extension = file.getAbsolutePath().substring(file.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf("."));
      String fileId = cachedFile.getEventCode() + "/" + cachedFile.getEmail().replace("%40","@") + "/" + cachedFile.getFileHash()  + extension;
      try{
         //fileId = URLEncoder.encode(fileId, "utf-8");
         TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(AwsUtility.BUCKET_NAME, fileId, file);
         transferObserverListener(transferObserver);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {

      }
      cachedFile.setFileId(fileId);

      return cachedFile;

   }

   public void transferObserverListener(TransferObserver transferObserver){

      transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener(){

         @Override
         public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            Log.i("SYNC_STATE", "State Change" + state);
         }

         @Override
         public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent/bytesTotal * 100);
            Log.i("SYNC_PROGRESS", "Progress in %" + percentage);
         }

         @Override
         public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            Log.e("error","error");
         }

      });
   }
```

I call the methods in this sequence:

```
s3credentialsProvide
 setTransferUtility
 uploadFileTos3
```

It is uploading to S3. But the problem is with the filename on S3:

```
TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(AwsUtility.BUCKET_NAME, fileId, file);
```

If I passed this value, "myemail@gmail.com/img-1.jpg" for the fileId, the file on the bucket became "myemail%40gmail.com/img-1.jpg". I do not want the @ character to be replaced. How can I solve the issue?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html https://stackoverflow.com/a/2637825/115145

Comment: I used UrlEncoder.encode("email") to  my email address. It is still not working as expected.

Comment: What does "the file on the bucket" mean? As the SO answer I pointed to mentions, download URLs have to be URL-encoded, and `@` is a reserved character that needs to URL-encoded.

Comment: But when we upload using PHP and other languages, the @ is not replaced. It is working. Is there a way to do the same in android? Because there are some existing systems using that format too. That is why.

Comment: So in my case what u saying is I just upload like this code now. But when I retrieve, I must encode the filename. Is it?

Comment: I am saying that I would follow [the S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html) and not use arbitrary characters in my keys.

Comment: I agree with @CommonsWare that using `@` in the path is a bad idea, because S3 handling of some special characters is a bit messy... but `@` is not actually reserved in all parts of a URI.  This seems like it could be called a bug in the Android SDK, if other SDKs behave differently.  Browsers do not seem to encode `@` in the path, so this forced encoding should probably not be in place.

Comment: Thank you, so much. Yeah, I will just consider this as an Android SDK bug and fix the existing system instead.

Comment: Hi @WaiYanHein, It's an bug introduced in the AWS Android SDK since 2.4.1. With releases before 2.4.1, it was working fine. We are working on to fix this.